# When do I need the "Enterprise" version of Exchange 2010 or Windows 2008R2?

Tags: exchange-2010

When would I need to install Windows 2008 Enterprise? Is this only for server clustering, otherwise is there a need for me to purchase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Key differences between Editions for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx)

"Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 is available in two server editions: Standard Edition and Enterprise Edition. Enterprise Edition can scale to 100 databases per server; Standard Edition is limited to 5 databases per server." per [MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232170.aspx)

Comment: +1. Also see here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I recall enterprise exchange allows for an greater or unlimited amount of storage groups.

yep that seems to be it
Enterprise Edition can scale to 100 databases per server; Standard Edition is limited to 5 databases per server.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232170.aspx

Comment: By segmenting our users into different SGs, we can easily control the different levels of email quotas.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if you need the Enterprise version of Exchange 2010, but if you want to use the HA features of Exchange 2010 Standard, you still need Windows Enterprise edition.

Comment: I have 80 databases... so yes I need Enterprise Exchange; thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also allowed four licensed virtual machines with each Windows Server 2008 Enterprise license.